# Atomic replace operation for mongo document

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm setting up a python application which uses mongodb (through pymongo).

I need to overwrite the contents of an entire document. This can be done either with [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) or [replace](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.replaceOne/). However, the mongo documentation isn't explicit about the atomicity of these operations - saying only that [individual write operations are atomic](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/), without explaining if update or replace use multiple write operations.

Does anyone know for sure if either of these operations is completely atomic?

Answer (score 0):

`find_and_modify` is deprecated in the `pymongo` driver. Instead use one of:

- [`find_one_and_delete`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one_and_delete)
- [`find_one_and_replace`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one_and_replace)
- [`find_one_and_update`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one_and_update)

The original `find_and_modify` had the potential to modify multiple documents which is probably not what was intended and is also not atomic.

For a truly ACID compiant sequence of modifications in MongoDB please look at [MongoDB ACID Transactions](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introduction-to-mongodb-transactions-in-python). Supported since MongoDB 4.0, released last year.